# Did you realize/ have you realized/ do you realize?

Tags: tense

I have a context like this: We are a group of 3 friends for almost 9 years. (Me, A and B)

I say to A:
We have been together for such a long time, didn't you realize that B always take advantage of you?

(1)... **didn't you realize** that B always take advantage of you?

(2)... **haven't you realized** that B always take advantage of you?

(3)... **don't you realize** that B always take advantage of you?

Which sentence is correct to use in this context? I think that (2) is the most appropriate to use.
How about (1) and (3)?

Answer (score 3):

*Don't you realize that B always **takes** advantage of you?* (A still isn't aware of it at the present time.) I would find this the most natural.

*Haven't you realized* (before now) would also be idiomatic.

*Didn't you realize* would be asking whether A was aware of it at some moment in the past.

Comment: If so, “did you realize “ is not correct to use in this context. Right?

Comment: It is certainly much less appropriate.

Comment: I am wondering if “did you realize “ is considered acceptable in American English in this context

Comment: @LEHANH _Did/Didn't you realize_ should always be used as a reference to past event. In the given example (1), the overall usage of tense sounds weird. It should be _didn't you realize that B "used to" always take advantage of you?_ or same as Kate Bunting's answer in present tense

Comment: I think it's misleading to say ***Didn't you realize...** would be asking whether A was aware of it at some moment in the past.* I think it's perfectly natural to say that ***while conveying the new information.*** That's to say, the time-frame referenced by ***Didn't you know he's married?*** could in principle just end at the word ***know*** - which the other person might only just be learning as those last two words are spoken.

Comment: Rakib and Kate Bunting disagree to use "didn't you realize.." in this context, but FumbleFingers accepts this , why do this happen?

Comment: I hesitated this morning to tell you that 'did you realise' was incorrect, as it had occurred to me that it _can_ sometimes be used in the context of the present - but I didn't have time to think or post any more.

Comment: @LEHANH Your understanding of tense takes precedence over colloquial or idiomatic usage. User FumbleFingers response refers to a very specific case, and the claim they are making that Did/didn't may be used other than referring to past event is also confusing. The purpose of this site is not to confuse people.

Comment: @Rakib - Fumblefingers is quite correct in saying that we often use **Didn't you know...?** when expressing surprise that someone wasn't previously aware of some fact. It is not a particularly 'special case' and not intended to confuse.

Comment: @KateBunting it _is_ confusing if someone demonstrates a particular use case as common. You yourself just used the word _often_. My response was targeted at the used tense of the sentence, which as I understand led OP to ask the question in the first place "Which one is correct/better". Now when someone says "Yes but you can also do X instead of Y, which is correct" - particularly when OP is looking for _either X or Y_ I call that confusing